# Find the object which contains an object with a specific property value in a nested list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a generated c# class from a XML file and I need to search in a Class Object. I will find a specified string in a List have a List but I don't know how to do this, I have tryed this but It wont work:

```
AdrType = HeaderObj.ClientObj.OrgObj.Addresses.First( s => s.AddressTypes.Select( aD => aD._Type_.Where(sX => sX = "a"))).AddressCode
```

Comment: It is difficult to Imagine and Assume your XML and Class So please also do provide your XML or Class to understand the code better

Comment: What exactly does not work? Does it compile? Is there an error message?

Comment: When you say "It wont work," what is the behavior that you're seeing?

Comment: You wrote `Where(sX => sX = "a")` and you probably meant `Where(sX => sX == "a")` instead. (notice the double `=` for comparsion)

Comment: Is `aD._Type_` an `IEnumerable`? You couldn't have `.Where` following when not. (If it is a string, it would be an `IEnumerable` of chars, but most probably not what you actually mean.)

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: It's a string and thats why I don't know how to do it  - I will have the first Address which List of addresstypes has a special string..

Comment: if it's just a string why just you don't compare the string directly instead

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: It's a string and thats why I don't know how to do it  - I will have the first Address which List of addresstypes has a special string, some AddressTypes has 8 strings in the List<AddressTypes> and I need the first which haves the "a" type

Comment: Its a List of Addresses with a List of AddressTypes and in the List of AddressTypes is a string I need

Comment: I tried to improve the title. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var adressWithTypeA = Addresses
  .FirstOrDefault( s => s.AddressTypes.Any(x => x._Type_ == "a"))

if (adressWithTypeA != null)
{
  var adressCode = adressWithTypeA.AddressCode;
}
```

Comment: this works thank you